# Running a dryer outlet to garage

Tags: electrical, wiring, conduit

Planning to Run a dryer outlet from outside service panel along the exterior wall approx 45 feet before entering the garage. What will be the correct size wire and conduit type to use?

Comment: Will the inside outlet be directly opposite where the run enters the garage?

Comment: yes, inside outlet will be directly opposite where the run enters.

Answer (score 4):

I would use EMT conduit and #10 THWN stranded wires.  One white wire and two wires that are black, brown, red, orange, yellow, pink, blue or purple.  They can be the same color.

EMT is its own grounding path, but if you want to be a completist, also run a single #10 green or bare wire.

Terminate that at a NEMA 14-30 socket.  If the dryer has a 3-prong cord, change it to a 14-30 plug and remove the neutral-ground strap.

Using an old NEMA 10 outlet is illegal and has been since the Bangles topped the charts.

No more than one 90 degree curve between access points. For hard corners use a **conduit body**, which is an access point.  1/2” EMT would suffice.  You can put up to 4 circuits in that conduit; if you expect more than 2, use 3/4" conduit.

Entry through the wall is also best done with a conduit body.

Comment: It's just another manic Monday

Comment: Do note that he'll darn well want to use a LB to enter the wall instead of trying to do it using a conduit bend

Comment: Thanks.I plan to use either 3/4 INCH shedule 40 or non metallic liquidtight conduit. Using THHN THWN STRANDED 10AWG 4 INDIVIDUAL wires.

Comment: ... Wish it was Sunday....